# Finding value within a div class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm parsing through a site where I come across something like:

```
<div class = "class-name" data-fmid="somenumber">
```

Using `beautiful soup`, how do I extract somenumber? I'm currently getting the elements related to class-name:

```
soup.find_all('div', {'class':'classname'})
```

but not sure how to get "somenumber". I'm using `beautifulsoup`, and pretty new to web-scraping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a single element

```
a = soup.find('div', {'class':"class-name"})
a['data-fmid']
```

If there are multiple divs you want to get the data from:

```
a = soup.find_all('div', {'class':"class-name"})
for ai in a :
    print(ai['data-fmid'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a css [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) as this is what they are for

```
items = [item['data-fmid'] for item in soup.select("[data-fmid]")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not what you are looking for. But, it may help. Because you didn't provide the URL you want to scrape, I just put an example of a website.

```
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://dnedesign.us.to/tables/'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

status = []
for div in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'mobile-menu-anchor fixed-primary-menu'}):
    print (''.join(div['id']))
```

You can change the value in `url` with the actual URL address, the name of `class` in the code with the actual class name, and change the `id` with the `data-fmid`.
Or if you want to get the `class` name and the `id` in each `div`, you can use this `loop`:

```
for div in soup.find_all('div'):
    try:
        print ('id : ' + ''.join(div['id']))
        print ('class : ' + ' '.join(div['class']))
        print()
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Identify the `div` through `class`:

```
all_num_class = soup.find_all('div', class_='classname') 
for ai in all_num_class:
    print(ai.get('data-fmid'))
```

Or you can use any `attr` to identify the `div` which you want to crawl:

```
all_num_class = soup.find_all('div', attr={'class':'classname'}) 
for ai in all_num_class:
    print(ai.get('data-fmid'))
```